# Footer div gets under another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with some text and another one that I'm filling it with a list of photos and a footer `div`. The footer `div` should be below photos `div` but it gets under it. This is my code:

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 2px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Software Engineer
</div>

<div id="test">
  <div id="comments">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 74</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  0</i>
        <button id="1547014733616513536_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 65</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1535724697949655394_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 68</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1501575131271622723_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background:blue;height:100px;width:100%">
    <div style="background:blue;height:200px;width:100%"></div>
  </div>
```

Ans here is a screenshot of it

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please remove the serverside code and post  an example code which the browser recieves.

Comment: Probably issue of `z-index`

Comment: you misspelled "height" (heoght)

Comment: @reporter Thanks for your offer please Check my corrected question

Comment: @abhishekkannojia How Can I Add this property?

Comment: @Honey Will it help if you add for div with id "footer" the style attribute `float:left`?

Comment: `clear:both` added as a footer ID tag in CSS. `#footer { clear:both; }` then html `<div id="footer"></div>` should do it. see my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Your floats are not cleared. Use @Chandras example or you can add a CSS ID `#footer { clear:both; }` and call on it in your footer div as you have in your example already. `<div id=footer">`.

**Bonus**, add your `style="width:100%; height:200px; background:blue; color:#FFF;"` line to your css file and remove the style attr from your div footer tag all together.

In your example snipit, I used a class with clear in your footers ID.
Check it:

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 2px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
   
#footer {
    clear:both;
    width:100%; 
    height:200px; 
    background:blue; 
    color:#FFF;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Software Engineer
</div>

<div id="test">
  <div id="comments">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 74</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  0</i>
        <button id="1547014733616513536_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 65</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1535724697949655394_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 68</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1501575131271622723_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer">Footer
  </div>
```

**FYI**
**Bootstrap V3** soon to release v4.
CDN: [Bootstrap CDN link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
BS V3 Grid System: [specific grid layout system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Bootstrap is an open source plugin that uses a standardized set of css and js rules already coded for you.

Among the *many* other awesome css and js additions, float your html tags using a standardized set of classes known as `cols`. These are used with media short cuts: `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, then add a division of 12, so you get something like. `<div class="gallery col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">` (col-md-4 means you are using up 4 of the 12 increments for a single div. You have 3 gallery divs, so `3 X 4 = 12` = `col-md-4`) These validate for different screen size media. 
Here is the layout from bootstrap grid per media:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

//  Extra small devices Phones (<768px) = .col-xs
//  Small devices Tablets (≥768px)      = .col-sm
//  Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)    = .col-md
//  Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)    = .col-lg
```

So by looking at my example, class="col-xs-12" on phones we would get one div that would be `width=100%;`. Where as "col-md-4" on lap tops and desk tops with resolution of any media larger than `992px` we would get the divs stacked side by side at `width=33.33%;`

Best to just read up on bootstrap as it is a bit to get into in one of these forums. It is actually very simple to add and use if you read up on it and how it works.

There is also [Bootply -> Bootstrap online editor](https://www.bootply.com/), there are some amazing tools there to help you get started using bootstrap!

Hope this helps...

Comment: I Add Your offer to my code Now The footer created But images Repeated

Comment: @honey Images repeated, in what way? Did you add an id rule for `clear:both;` in your css file and call on it in your footer div? Perhaps you can update your snipit with your current code so we can take a look at it and see why it may be repeating images. Make sure to add all relevant CSS and html please. The example I posted does not repeat any extra images, only the ones in your three divs.

Comment: Thanks!I Add `clear:both` property And my problem solved

Comment: Glad this helped out Honey. Best of luck coding!

Answer (score 2):

Issue may be because of the floats. Try using Clearfix

Try adding this class to comments.
(Modified Some HTML)

Give this a try.

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Software Engineer
</div>

<div id="test"> 
  <div id="comments" class="clearfix">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 74</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  0</i>
        <button id="1547014733616513536_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 65</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1535724697949655394_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 68</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1501575131271622723_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="background:blue;width:100%">
  <div style="background:blue;width:100%"> footer div here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 2px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Software Engineer
</div>

<div id="test">
  <div id="comments" class="clearfix">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 74</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  0</i>
        <button id="1547014733616513536_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 65</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1535724697949655394_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 68</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1501575131271622723_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="background:blue;width:100%">
  <div style="background:blue;width:100%"> footer div here</div>
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/esp1jrp3/4/)

Hope this helps…

Comment: This code only repeats the picture for me, not the other thing

Comment: @Honey try the link above

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `float` are removed from normal document flow. You should `clear` `float`s when using them.

But I suggest you to rewrite your `float` code using flexbox. In this case you can remove `float`s because they will be ignores. Demo:

```css
#comments {
  /* specify element as flex-container */
  /* its children will be treated as flex items */
  display: flex;
  /* allow moving elements to next line */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 280px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 2px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Software Engineer
</div>

<div id="test">
  <div id="comments">
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 74</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  0</i>
        <button id="1547014733616513536_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 65</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1535724697949655394_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://example.com">
      <div class="desc">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:red;"> 68</i>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o" style="color:#333;">  1</i>
        <button id="1501575131271622723_414010731">comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background:blue;height:100px;width:100%">
    <div style="background:blue;heoght:200px;width:100%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace This Code.

```
<div style="background:blue;height:200px;width:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue that your comments container height is not correct, it is is not considering the inner nodes size.

So give comments `overflow:hidden;` or a fixed `height` or `minheight`

Comment: I Add overflow property But Don't Work for me.And What do you mean by false altitudes?

Comment: @Honey I didn't say anything about false attributes, did I?!

Comment: Sorry!I Edited height property

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```